# program against known method, not the type

Tags: c#, .net

Lets say I have a class `A` which is going to be compiled into a `dll` to be used later. But I kind of know that later, some methods of class `B` which I am not aware of its type must be called in `A` class. The only clue is the name of the methods.

Lets say this is class `A`:

```
public class A
{
    A(Object instanceOfClassB)
    {
          //stuff...
    }

    public void SendProcessedString()
    {
         //some strings has been processd, I know that class B is going
         //to have a public method like ReceiveData(string data){/*---*/}
         instanceOfClassB.ReceiveData(data);
    }
}
```

Lets say this is class `B`, happen to be a WinForm:

```
public B : Form
{
     public void ReceiveData(string data)
     {
          textBox.Append(data + Environment.NewLine);
     }
}
```

Is such approach possible/recommended?

Comment: What does this has to do with *dynamic programming?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is possible using the `dynamic` keyword (in C# 4.0 or higher).  Check the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) for more info.

However, this leads to incredibly loose programming and can cause runtime issues that are difficult to debug.  You're much better off creating an interface that class B will implement.

```
public class A
{
    A(IDataReceiver instanceOfClassB)
    {
          //stuff...
    }

    public void SendProcessedString()
    {
         //some strings has been processd, I know that class B is going
         //to have a public method like ReceiveData(string data){/*---*/}
         instanceOfClassB.ReceiveData(data);
    }
}

public B : Form, IDataReceiver
{
     public void ReceiveData(string data)
     {
          textBox.Append(data + Environment.NewLine);
     }
}

public interface IDataReceiver
{
    void ReceiveData(string data);
}
```

Comment: Are you stealing my answer? I stole yous as well ;)

Comment: yeah....I was looking for dynamic...had read about it somewhere long time ago. Interface I know by heart lol...but the point is in my case I am not able to tell others are going to implement from the interface...so I go with dynamic and hope for the best.

Comment: @SaeidYazdani If you're not sure whether class B will implement the interface, you can check for it by using `instanceOfClassB is IDataReceiver`.  This way you can take an `object` in the class B constructor, check to see if it implements the interface, and if so, cast it to an `IDataReceiver` and send the data.  Dan-o's answer with callbacks and/or events may also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using interface. You class B must implement "MyInterface" interface and "MyInterface" should have method which are are expecting A to call.

```
public class A
{
    A(MyInerface instanceOfClassB)
    {
          //stuff...
    }

    public void SendProcessedString()
    {
         //some strings has been processd, I know that class B is going
         //to have a public method like ReceiveData(string data){/*---*/}
         instanceOfClassB.ReceiveData(data);
    }
}
```

If it is not possible to implement interface at class B, you need to use reflection. See here ([How to use reflection to call method by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110280/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-method-by-name)) on how to call a method from a Type (so you will have to pass the type in constructor of A.

Comment: Also, with .NET 4.0,  you can use "dynamic" keyword to make your reflection code look good :)

Comment: Dynamic is a very bad practice for type safe languages. You should use `interfaces` and other `polymorphic` tools instead

Comment: That's what I suggested, Dynamic is alternate of Reflection. My bad - I edited my comment to indicate that.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds you need to use an `interface`.
A little information about `interfaces` can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx).

Basically you want to create an `interface` and get it as a parameter for `class A` and implement it in `class B`:

```
interface IDataReceiver
{
    void ReceiveData(string data);
}
```

then `class B` decleration will look like:

```
public B : Form, IDataReceiver
```

And class A` constructor:

```
A(IDataReceiver dataReceiver)
{
    //stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option here would be to use events.  Have your raise an event instead of invoking the callback.

*excuse my C#, I'm a little rusty*

```
public class classA {
    public event DataReceived(string data);

    public void SendProcessedString() {
        // you got var data from somewhere
        DataReceived(data)
    }
}
```

Then subscribe to that event from your classB

```
// classB setup code or initializer:
instanceA.DataReceived += dataReceivedHandler;

private void dataReceivedHandler(string data) {
    // do something with the data.
}
```

Comment: Good answer.  The only hiccup is if the DLL that contains class A references the DLL that contains class B - in that case, class B can't know about class A to subscribe to the callback.

Comment: @nintendojunkie: Absolutely.  I would think though that in that situation the type definition of classB would be known to classA.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another method is to use a proper callback - only if a single subscriber is guaranteed.  If you need multiple subscribers use an event.

```
public class classA {
    public Action<string> DataReceivedCallback = null;

    public void SendProcessedString() {
        if (null != DataReceivedCallback) { DataReceivedCallback.Invoke(data); }
    }
}
```

*somewhere in classB*

```
instanceA.DataReceivedCallback = new Action<string>(dataReceivedHandler);

private void dataReceivedHandler(string data) {
    // do something with the data.
}
```