# Invoke Method with reflection pass through parameters and receive a return value

Tags: c#, reflection

Hello as the question describes im trying to invoke a method through reflection, which is fine and all if it was a void type. but string, bool, etc is not working. also with a return type. i haven't been able to find any useful references.

i have a Test Class which i used to call some test methods. all the void ones had worked fine. but the others were not calling at all.

```
internal class Test
{
    public static void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
        Console.WriteLine("Testing an invoke method");
    }

    public static void CalcData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
    }

    public static void DoSomething(int c, float f)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
    }

    public static string TestString(string s, int p, char f)
    {
        return "Happy Days";
    }
}
```

in my Main Method i would call `t.GetMethod("Print").Invoke(t, null);`

but i am unsure how i would call to pass in a parameter or even obtain a return type.

some insight on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use reflection to call method by name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110280/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-method-by-name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the signature of [`MethodInfo.Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public object Invoke(
    object obj,
    object[] parameters
)
```

You need to pass the parameters of the method in the `parameters` `object[]`. Note that the method returns an `object`, you just need to cast it to the result type.

A call to `TestString` should look like this:

```
var parameters = new object[]{"A string", 10, 'a'};
string result = (string) t.GetMethod("Print").Invoke(t, parameters);
```

Comment: thank you this worked perfectly. 

well i had to make a hand full of adjustments but i can now call any method over the network like this with few restrictions =)

Comment: Looks good to me. 
I want to know about the meaning of return values by the invoke method. 
for example if Invoke method returns 16 or 9. What error it is. 
When Invoke command returns 0, this means the command runs successfully.