# How to invoke c# function from another project without adding reference?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

There is a C#.net library project whose DLL name is `customer.dll`. It has a class name `customer` with a function name `show()`. I want to call this function from another project but don't want to add the reference to the caller project. Can this be done? Is there any C#.net class that can achieve this?

Comment: you can check how to use reflection in c#. assembly load and access the Method create a instances and access the method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use reflection to call method by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110280/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-method-by-name)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can load assemblies dynamically using `Assembly.LoadFile`

```
Assembly.LoadFile("c:\\somefolder\\Path\\To\\Code.dll");
```

You are then going to need to use Reflection to get the methodinfo for the function you want to invoke or use the Dynamic keyword to invoke it.

```
var externalDll = Assembly.LoadFile("c:\\somefolder\\Customer.dll");
var externalTypeByName = externalDll.GetType("CustomerClassNamespace.Customer");

// If you don't know the full type name, use linq
var externalType = externalDll.ExportedTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Customer");

//if the method is not static create an instance.
//using dynamic 
dynamic dynamicInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(externalType);
var dynamicResult = dynamicInstance.show();

// or using reflection
var reflectionInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(externalType);
var methodInfo = theType.GetMethod("show");
var result = methodInfo.Invoke(reflectionInstance, null);

// Again you could also use LINQ to get the method
var methodLINQ = externalType.GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "show");
var resultLINQ = methodLINQ.Invoke(reflectionInstance, null);
```

Comment: Thank you.But What should i write to achieve this .Please Give me some link then i can easily follow

Comment: Confused. I just showed you how to load the DLL and invoke the method. You simply need to change the path to the DLL and TypeName parameters.  If you need further documentation Google `Assembly.LoadFile` and check out the reference documents on MSDN.

Comment: Oh Great. Thank You so much You saved my time

Comment: One more thing i am getting error in theType and method.

Comment: What error? You can use LINQ to find the type `var externalType = externalDll.ExportedTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Customer");`  Same for the method

Comment: Great!! Thank You

Comment: I am getting Exception->Absolute path information is required. Assembly.LoadFile()

Comment: The put an absolute path in there. "c:\\somefolder\customer.dll"

Comment: But the problem is it can be change and my file extension is .exe not .dll .

Comment: So how can i do this

Comment: Some exe's are .net modules and can be loaded the same way. Your question said you had `customer.dll` Many times exe's have dll's they reference. If not you'll have to ask for a DLL.

Comment: Sorry my mistake i saw after build it created exe not dll.