# C# invoke function in foreach loop

Tags: c#, foreach

I have:

1. Json file which contains list of names (MyfunctionA, MyfunctionB, MyfunctionC)
2. Visual studio project contains multiple functions, each function name is the same as in Json file.

   ```
   public static void MyfunctionA() {}
   public static void MyfunctionB() {}
   public static void MyfunctionC() {}
   ```

I am trying to achieve:

1. I deserialize Json file to get object.

   ```
   dynamic MyJsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
   ```
2. I use foreach loop

   ```
   foreach (var obj in MyJsonObject) {
       // My code here
   }
   ```

How to call each function in foreach loop?

Comment: Please add the example of your json.

Comment: Here you can see how to execute a method by name using Reflection: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3110313/2877982

Comment: Why `dynamic`? Apart from that: _"How to call each function in foreach loop?"_ - Reflection.

Comment: Doesn't make sense that you  need to call the deserialize in a loop.  You should be getting back one response and deserialize only once.

Comment: @jdweng Huh? As far as I can tell, OP is planning to do exactly that.

Comment: ^^ *Reflection*, _but_ in this case, I'd probably use reflection only to build a `Dictionary<string, Action>` _once_ in the app's lifetime. Then use that as lookup. I guess you might want to restrict the set of functions that shall be callable in this manner, right?

Comment: I deserialize only once to convert Json string to object, then I run foreach loop . My idea is: I do not want to call hundreds of functions one by one, I want to run a loop to write less code.

Comment: Voted to reopen. Actually, I think there is a better solution than Reflection, here - if it is reasonable for OP.

Comment: So what is the best way to achieve that? I hope I explained it clearly.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y1Z8TQ Maybe it's feasable to you. It's just a scribble, so you'll probably want to play around with the idea.

Comment: This is it, thank you.

Comment: @Fildor : Usually you have to get a response and deserialize each response one at a time.  Here the op is getting an array of json objects.  When do you ever see more than one json object for each response?

Comment: @jdweng honestly, I have no idea what you're talking about. (No offense) The question doesn't mention "response" _anywhere_.

Comment: @Fildor : Where does the json come from.  Normally you get json response from a server.

Comment: @jdweng _"Json **file** which contains list of names"_ ... so I jumped to the conclusion it's from the file system. Maybe I am mistaken, though ...

Comment: @Fildor : What OP is asking is confusing.  The list a names is not the json but the classes.  I'm not sure where the array is coming from unless the is more than one file or more than one conneciton.

Comment: _"What OP is asking is confusing."_ - agreed.

Comment: Is is super simple :) I will edit my question later with example