# Create an instance of a class sent by parameter / Delegates

Tags: c#, view, delegates, vsto, customtaskpane

I am trying to optimize my code a bit by either using [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e(v=vs.71).aspx) or using a [class instance as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194949/how-to-use-class-name-as-parameter-in-c-sharp). I am pretty new to C# and I am not yet sure which one is the better approach assuming im on the right track in the first place. But my problem relates to sending a class instance as parameter. Let me explain. I am trying to follow [this logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194949/how-to-use-class-name-as-parameter-in-c-sharp) but im failiing.... 
I have created a VSTO Ribbon with a few buttons. It looks somewhat like this:

[image: Ribbon]
Now, I am now trying to add some functionality to the buttons, so a click on each button opens a new TaskPane.

I wrote this code for the `Calendar` Ribbon button which sits in the `GSMRibbon.cs`
*note: I think that for the more experienced programmers this code will be quite easy to understand but in case you guys dont understand something please let me know in the comments i will explain ).*

```
namespace GSM
{
    public partial class GSMRibbon
    {
        private void GSMRibbon_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs 
        {
        }

        private CustomTaskPane taskPane;

        private CustomTaskPane TaskPane
        {
            get
            {
                return this.taskPane;
            }
        }

        private void vendors_calendar_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            string newTitle = "PO Calendar";

            if (TaskPane != null)
            {
                if (TaskPane.Title != newTitle)
                {
                    Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Remove(TaskPane);
                    CreateTaskPane(newTitle);
                }
                else
                {
                    taskPane.Visible = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                CreateTaskPane(newTitle);
            }
        }

        private void CreateTaskPane(string title)
        {
            var taskPaneView = new CalendarView();
            taskPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(taskPaneView, title);
            taskPane.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Ok. What I wanted to do was to modify the CreateTaskPane function adding a `class` parameter (does this make sense?) so I can re-use this function multiple times for different buttons on the ribbon. I have created a separate `View` for each of the buttons, but I am not sure how to pass the `View`.

So, im after something like this: (CalendarView is the name of the View)

```
CreateTaskPane(new CalendarView(), newTitle);
```

and the function something like:

```
private void CreateTaskPane(object typeOfView, string title)
{
    var taskPaneView = new (typeOfView)Object;
    taskPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(taskPaneView, title);
    taskPane.Visible = true;
}
```

I really hope you understand what I am trying to but being unable to do myself. I appreciate any attempt to help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use generics to do this:

```
private void CreateTaskPane<T>(string title) where T : UserControl, new()
{
    T taskPaneView = new T();
    taskPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(taskPaneView, title);
    taskPane.Visible = true;
}
```

You would then call it via:

```
CreateTaskPane<CalendarView>(newTitle);
```

Alternatively, you could write this as:

```
private void CreateTaskPane<T>(T taskPaneView, string title) where T : UserControl
{
    taskPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(taskPaneView, title);
    taskPane.Visible = true;
}
```

Then call via:

```
CreateTaskPane(new CalendarView(), newTitle);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be looking for is [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

The function you would end up with is something like:

```
private void CreateTaskPane<T>(string title) where T : UserControl, new()
{
   var taskPaneView = new T();
   taskPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(taskPaneView, title);
   taskPane.Visible = true;
}

// Later on..
CreateTaskPane<CalenderTaskPane>("Calender");
```

Comment: Your generic constraints aren't correct here - T is actually a `UserControl`, not the `TaskPane`, and you'd also need a new constraint or the constructor call will fail.

Comment: Whoops, thanks! Been a while since I used generic constraints :)