# How can I use string value for passing Type for Type<T> parameter?

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to create a list of object of `Student` in `School`. Instead of `Student` the `School` can also have `Teacher` as a list. I want to use the class name as a parameter instead of the actual class type as a parameter while initiating class.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       //School object with list of student
        var schoolWithStudent = SchoolWithOject("Student");
        //School object with list of teacher
        var schoolWithTeacher = SchoolWithOject("Teacher");
    }

    public static object SchoolWithOject(string objType)
    {
        var objType = Type.GetType("objType");
        var school = new School<objType>();
        return school;
    }   
}

public class School<T>
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    private List<T> _components;

    public School()
    {
        _components = new List<T>();
    }
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}

public class Teacher
{
    int Id;
    string Name;
}
```

Comment: Have you asked yourself why you would want this?  Your code does not seem dynamic at all, what is wrong with `new School<Student>();`?

Comment: Also, if Teacher and Student have the same properties (or share some number of properties) it should be abstracted into a base class or an interface (like `Person` or something).  That way you can restrict your `School<T>` to only allow the common abstraction

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194949/how-to-use-class-name-as-parameter-in-c-sharp

Comment: I have written this code just to demonstrate the problem. In real time I won't be aware of which Class it would be using. I would just have Class in my project. The Type of list selection needs to be dynamic and passed at the runtime.

Comment: `School<T>` means each school object can only have one type of list (that type being `T`, which you provide when using `new`). That seems like the wrong abstraction; you can have a school of only students, or a school of only teachers, but not a school with both.

Comment: Might help to look up dependency injection...

Comment: @maccettura Student and Teacher are just for demo purpose, the actual code would have totally different properties list.

Comment: @JoeSewell Yes, I won't be needing school object with both student and teacher. I would be only needing one either one at a time. I just want to use string value to initialize by list type in school.

Comment: Please refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078914/creating-a-generict-type-instance-with-a-variable-containing-the-type

Comment: @user8759979 var specificListType = genericListType.MakeGenericType(typeof("Student")); . This wont work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly and you are not forced to use generics, I would recommend the following solution.

Since a school contains students and teachers you can implement an interface for both types.

```
interface IPerson
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}

class Student : IPerson
{
    // student specific stuff
}

class Teacher : IPerson
{
    // teacher specific stuff
}
```

So your school looks like this:

```
public class School
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    private List<Person> _persons;

    public School()
    {
        _persons = new List<Person>();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem would this approach would that the Dynamic Class won't be implementing the interface. They can be anything.

Comment: Maybe try to find a better example or description of your problem.

Comment: I have just edit the code. Hope it explains my problem a bit better.   Thank you for your answer.